# Load balancer/reverse proxy: "upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream" in docker-swarm?

Tags: docker, nginx, load-balancing, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm

I am running 1 manager and 2 workers nodes in docker-swarm.

The worker nodes are running 3 stacks with php/nginx website, so that's site1, site2, site3 that load "This is site*/(worker1 or worker2)" in the browser.
That works fine when I put a reverse proxy on one of the nodes.

But I want to put a single load balancer/reverse proxy on the manager node, I also disabled the other 2 stacks so in this example only "site1" stack is on both worker nodes. Their Ip's are "10.0.14.16" and "10.0.14.17".

This is the LB/RP nignx configuration file.

```
   upstream site1_nginx  {
     server 10.0.14.16;
     server 10.0.14.17;
   }
   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name site1.local;

       location / {
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass http://site1_nginx;

       }
   }
```

and this is the docker compose file of the nignx:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      deploy:
        placement:
          constraints:
            - node.role==manager
        mode: global
      ports:
          - "80:80"
      volumes:
          - "./conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d"

      networks:
          - reprox
networks:
  reprox:
    external: true
```

But I get this error when I create the service:

```
loadbalancer_nginx.0.ua0z0l8gm18e@ubuntu-vm1    | 2019/10/11 14:36:00 [error] 6#6: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.2, server: site1.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.14.17:80/", host: "site1.local"
loadbalancer_nginx.0.ua0z0l8gm18e@ubuntu-vm1    | 2019/10/11 14:36:00 [warn] 6#6: *12 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.2, server: site1.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.14.17:80/", host: "site1.local"
loadbalancer_nginx.0.ua0z0l8gm18e@ubuntu-vm1    | 2019/10/11 14:36:00 [error] 6#6: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.2, server: site1.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.14.16:80/", host: "site1.local"
loadbalancer_nginx.0.ua0z0l8gm18e@ubuntu-vm1    | 2019/10/11 14:36:00 [warn] 6#6: *12 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.2, server: site1.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.0.14.16:80/", host: "site1.local"
loadbalancer_nginx.0.ua0z0l8gm18e@ubuntu-vm1    | 2019/10/11 14:36:01 [error] 6#6: *12 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.2, server: site1.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://site1_nginx/", host: "site1.local"
```

Also if you need, the site1 nginx site configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.php index.html;
    server_name site1.local;
    resolver 127.0.0.11;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /code;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        set $upstream php:9000;        
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass $upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

docker networks are fine, I do have an overlay network and network between php and nignx.

Answer (score 0):

Docker swarm has its own load balancer, network and DNS system. If you want to use your own balancer there is no reason to define IP addresses of the nodes because docker provides an abstraction and manages service discovery for you as well.

The solution with IP routing wouldn't work as you think because of [routing mesh](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/). All requests get load balanced without consideration of the node that gets the traffic. You can visit IP1 and due to routing mesh IP2 can process the request.

What do you want is to refer to your site as the DNS record you've defined as a service name.

Like this

```
upstream site1_nginx  {
    server site1:80;
}
```

`site1` is the service name defined in `docker-compose.yml` (nginx has the DNS name as `nginx`).

You can refer to the service as particular replica but then you need to implement health check by yourself.

```
upstream site1_nginx  {
    server site1.1:80;
    server site1.2:80;
    server site1.3:80;
}
```

Comment: I just get this error:
```
loadbalancer_nginx.0.sfs1ty1pajt9@ubuntu-vm1    | 2019/10/14 09:47:16 [error] 6#6: *5 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 10.255.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://site1_nginx/", host: "site1.local"
```
And this when I remove and create the service:
```
host not found in upstream "site1:80" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/site1.conf:10
```

Comment: Do you have `nginx` as part of the docker swarm services network or you have it separately installed on the host?

Comment: There is an overlay network called "reprox" as you can see in docker compose file it is specified for nginx LB/RP to connect to it, also the site1_nginx is connected to that network (that nginx is running with site1_php in a stack on worker nodes, php is connected to that nginx with a seperate network).

Like I said, when I run the reverse proxy on the worker node, it loads the sites, but when I remove that reverse proxy and put it on manager node that doesn't have any services it won't automatically connect to the stacks on worker nodes even though they ar eon the same "reprox" network.

Comment: I followerd this tutorial: https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/05/load-balancing-docker-swarm-cluster-nginx-reverse-proxy/

But it won't let me have this part:
```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;
```
So nginx will load when I remove those lines but then I get 502 bad gateway.

Comment: Can you access your services from manager node with the plain `curl` command?

Comment: No.
"curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.14.16 port 80: Connection refused"

Comment: I added ufw rules for ports and http, and also disabled ufw altogether, but nothing works.

Comment: Have you published your services to the public port `80`? Can you access it locally on the `10.0.14.16` node by `curl http://localhost:80`?

Comment: I just gave up, gonna try with centos VMs and if I get to the same point I will answer.

Comment: Alright, centos setup, same problem and no I can't curl localhost. I can't curl worker IPs because reverse proxy isn't running on them and reverse proxy then communicates with the stack. This is docker-compose file for the stack on worker nodes:

Comment: ```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      deploy:
        placement: 
          constraints: 
            - node.role==worker
        mode: global 
      volumes:
          - "./code:/code"
          - "./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf"
      networks:
          - site1
          - reprox
  php:
      image: php:7-fpm
      deploy:
        placement: 
          constraints: 
            - node.role==worker
        mode: global      
      volumes:
          - "./code:/code"
      networks:
        - site1
```

Comment: ```
networks:
  reprox:
    external: true 
  site1:
```
As you can see, it's not binded to any ports, only the site.conf listens to port 80 if you go back to orginial post.

So I have really no idea what to do.

Comment: If you can publish a repo with reproducible example, I can look into it :)

Comment: Also I updated the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393434/reverse-proxy-service-on-manager-node-host-not-found-in-upstream-but-it-works